# Elementary OS Juno - Setting the Super Key to unhide/hide/Toggle On-Screen Keyboard

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, touchscreen

18.04.2 LTS

I am switching from Mac OS X and iOS to Elementary OS.

I am replacing both my desktop computer and my iPad with a Dell Inspiron 11 3000 series 2-in-1 special edition (3153).

The 3153 has a Super Key on the bezel.

When in Tablet mode, I'd like to be able to simply press the bezel Super key to unhide the On-Screen Keyboard, and when finished with the On-Screen Keyboard, press the Super key again on the 3153's bezel to hide it.

I've attempted to achieve the desired behavior in System Settings>Keyboard>Shortcuts>Windows by disabling the "toggle on Keyboard Shortcuts" by the Super key, disabling "Toggle On Screen keyboard" in System Settings>Keyboard>Shortcuts>Universal Access, and attempted to enable "Toggle On Screen keyboard" via the Super key in System Settings>Keyboard>Shortcuts>Universal Access, to no avail.

I've searched this board, and have found no posting with a solution to to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance for assistance.

Comment: Try asking the eOS devs directly (as an issue report or a feature request) at https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-keyboard/issues

Comment: "Try asking the eOS devs directly (as an issue report or a feature request) at github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-keyboard/issues – a-tokarev Oct 28 at 22:13"


Did that 6 days ago - no response.

Comment: Well, what can I say, either they're too busy creating something great, or that was their response.